# Viewbag broken in Visual Studio 2017 RC and ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.1

I upgraded my project to Visual Studio 2017 RC

I get the following runtime error:

> Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

when accessing a page that references `ViewBag` in my cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page Title";
}
```

I have added `Microsoft.CSharp` to my references but I still get the error

The only solution was to change all my references from `ViewBag.Item` to `ViewData["Item"]`